# Unsubscribing from events and being sure that the handler will not be called again

Tags: c#, events

I have a chat session class which has a MessageReceived event which is raised whenever a message is received. The session class also has a Disconnect event to close the session and prevent further messages from being received.

```
    public class Session
    {
        event EventHandler<string> MessageReceived;
        public void Disconnect();
    }
```

I subscribe to the Session's MessageReceived event, and in my handler I decode the message and then use it to update the application -- eg.. a message could contain updates about a particular user, or a message about the user joining, etc.

When I want to close my application the first thing I do is unsubscribe from the MessageReceived event, and then call Disconnect. Then I go about cleaning up and disposing of all the resources used by the application.

Now if I didn't give it much thought, I might assume that just because I have unsubscribed from MessageReceived and called Disconnect that it's not possible for any more MessageReceived events to be raised. This is obviously not the case. It's still entirely possible that right before I unsubscribed and called Disconnect that the event handler had already started.

The problem here is that after I call Disconnect I proceed to cleanup and dispose of the applications resources, but these are the same resources that could be hypothetically accessed inside my MessageReceived handler. It's an unhandled exception waiting to happen.

After I've called Disconnect, I want to be certain that the event handler will not be called again before I proceed with teardown.

Can SO please advise me on what the best practices are in this situation, and preferably point to examples in the .NET framework where this situation is encountered and dealt with.

Thank you

Comment: right before you unsubscribe from MessageReceived set a flag to let yourself know that any future MessageReceived events received should be ignored.  In the event handler simply check the flag an immediately return if it's true.  If you're thinking this could happen over multiple threads you might want to write to the value with Volatile.Write and read from it with Volatile.Read.

Comment: A boolean flag isn't enough. Let's say you check the flag at the beginning of the event handler, then Thread.Sleep(5000) and then do some processing. How is the flag going to stop a thread which has already checked the flag and is still running?

Comment: It doesn't stop the thread, there's nothing you can do about that, you can only keep track of *your* state--in which case you simply ignore the event if called after you unsubscribe.  i.e. the Boolean flag violatily accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about race conditions, protect critical resources with a Monitor (lock)

[Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179%28VS.80%29.aspx)

**EDIT**:
You can use a flag as suggested above, and protect the flag with a monitor:

```
object lockThis = new object();
bool isSubscribed = false;
...
lock(lockThis){
  publisher.SomeEvent += handler;
  isSubscribed = true;
}

... then in the handler

lock(lockThis){
   if (isSubscribed){
     // do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Or, you can use `Volatile.Read/Write`, as suggested above, and you don't need `lock`.

Answer (score -1):

One standard way for dealing with this in systems that have to process stimuli from multiple sources is to funnel all stimuli and their parameters into a queue that is thread safe, and then have one dedicated thread processing these items.

From there, shutting down is pretty easy. Enqueue a 'stop' event into the queue, and then easy enough the thread processing the queue sees the stop event and stops looking at the queue.

This is the model that Windows uses for UI events.

So, that's how you'd handle it if you had, for example 5 network interfaces and a thread each receiving packets and want to make sure that the agent that processes events does so in a safe way. This is a little overkill for what you need though, but it helps you think about the problem from a more general standpoint.

So here's one idea that assumes your event handler only ever gets fired from one thread and the code that triggers the shutdown doesn't have to wait for the shutdown to finish; if it doesn't, this isn't going to work. Anyway, to shutdown, manually fire the event, telling it the message is a fake shutdown message. It'll set a flag to indicate that it is shut down, then deregister the event handler, then do the shutdown calls. Assuming the event handler only ever happens on one thread, you'll be guaranteed that you'll only ever try shutting down internal state from this thread.

If the event can be fired from multiple threads, then this doesn't work - for instance, if the UI thread is the one firing it for the shutdown, but the socket receive thread is the one firing it for real events. Also, if your shutdown initiating code has to wait for the real shutdown to finish, for some other reason, then this won't work because it has no way of waiting for the event to signal safely that it's done. That might not be a problem, if you move all of the real shutdown code to inside the event handler.

So here's another way of handling this, that's a little more complicated: you can't let your shutdown code progress while you're still in the event hander; and the event handler can't be entered if you've already started the shutdown.

You need some locks.

When you enter your event handler, grab a lock. If you get the lock and find out that your shutdown flag is set, then just return. Else, while still under the lock, process your event.

When you enter your shutdown code, grab the lock. Set that you are shutting down. Release the lock. Deregister the event handler and do the cleanup.

If you were processing an event when the shutdown code ran, then the shutdown code would block on the lock until the event finished.

Its possible that an event can happen while you are in the shutdown code, holding the lock. The event code will block waiting for the lock. You'll release the lock after marking the shutdown flag as being set, then start doing the shutdown. So, you'll release the lock, the event code will wake up, the shutdown code will keep running, the event code will see that the shutdown flag is set, and it'll exit without touching any resources.

Comment: "just return".  How do you need locks for that?  What's wrong with a simple Boolean?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, the point is to make sure that you don't call the shutdown code while the event handler is running. The event handler holds the lock the entire time its running, but the first thing it does is check if the shutdown flag is set. Without the lock, you'll risk, say, closing your socket from the shutdown code while the event handler is read/writing to it.

Comment: yep, since "If the event can be fired from multiple threads, then this doesn't work" is plain wrong if you use thread synchronization to guard the flag.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, that's why there are two approaches, one that doesn't use locks, and one that does, depending on how the asker's system works, which is unclear as written. Please read my entire answer.

Comment: You can do it without locks.

Comment: You can do this without locks, if you can make some assumptions about how events are processed and how the shutdown code is fired. Since I don't know those assumptions, again, I gave two answers, one that uses locks and one that doesn't.

Comment: A simple flag isn't enough to implement this. The shutdown code would set the flag and then start closing resources. If the event handler is running, then it's already past the point where it would look at the flag, and when the shutdown code starts closing resources, the event handler code would break.

Comment: You don't need a lock to wait for the event handle to finish.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27214/discussion-between-antiduh-and-peter-ritchie)